# Oracle turn rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

```
station     node        group
13859160    13195576    high
13859160    42502030    low
13859165    42283197    low
13859165    42283198    high
13859166    13190800    low
13859166    13190801    low
13859166    13195587    high
```

It can be created with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes
    ("station" int, "node" int, "group" varchar(6))
;
```

and filled with this statement:

```
insert into nodes values (13859160, 13195576,   'high');
insert into nodes values (13859160, 42502030,   'low');
insert into nodes values (13859165, 42283197,   'low');
insert into nodes values (13859165, 42283198,   'high');
insert into nodes values (13859166, 13190800,   'low');
insert into nodes values (13859166, 13190801,   'low');
insert into nodes values (13859166, 13195587,   'high');
```

I want to query this table so that high and low become columns, so that the result looks like this:

```
Station     high        low
13859160    13195576    42502030
13859165    42283198    42283197
13859166    13195587    13190801
13859166    13195587    13190800
```

If there where no stations that had multiple "low" rows, it would be easy, I could just do something like this to get the high and low:

```
select 
    "station",
    case when "group" = 'high' then "node" end as high,
    case when "group" = 'low' then "node" end as low
from "NODES";
```

which results in:

[image]

and then use a aggregate function to get the results on one like:

```
select 
    "station",
    max(case when "group" = 'high' then "node" end) as high,
    max(case when "group" = 'low' then "node" end) as low
from "NODES"
group by "station";
```

This results in:

[image]

However, when 1 startion has multiple "low" enties, I need one row for each low entry, that row should contain the same "high" entry for that station in both rows.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: This is a very common question. Please look at some of [these existing threads for `oracle+pivot`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+pivot)

Comment: what if there are multiple highs and lows?

Comment: there wil only be one high per station, but there can be multiple lows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I might suggest `listagg()` for the aggregation query:

```
select "station",
       listagg(case when "group" = 'high' then "node" end) as high,
       listagg(case when "group" = 'low' then "node" end) as low
from "NODES"
group by "station";
```

To get multiple rows for a single station, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select "station",
       max(case when "group" = 'high' then "node" end) as high,
       max(case when "group" = 'low' then "node" end) as low
from (select n.*,
             row_number() over (partition by "station", "group" order by "node") as seqnum
      from "NODES" n
     ) n
group by "station", seqnum;
```

Finally, if you want the last max value to be repeated:

```
select "station",
       coalesce(max(case when "group" = 'high' then "node" end),
                max(max(case when "group" = 'high' then "node" end)) over (partition by "station)
               ) as high,
       max(case when "group" = 'low' then "node" end) as low
from (select n.*,
             row_number() over (partition by "station", "group" order by "node") as seqnum
      from "NODES"
     ) n
group by "station", seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.

```
select * from (
select 
    "station",
    max(case when "group" = 'high' then "node" end) over(partition by "station") as high,
    case when "group" = 'low' then "node" end as low
from nodes
) n
where low is not null
```